# Validar que un rango de fechas no se encuentre ya en una tabla de rangos de fechas (desde-hasta)

Tags: java

lo que necesito es verificar que una nueva fecha con un nuevo rango no se encuentre entre fechas ya ingresadas anteriormente en una base de datos ejemplo.

```
fecha_inicio    fecha_fin
10-10-2010      15-10-2010
16-10-2010      19-10-2010
```

si quisiera meter una fecha como

```
17-10-2010     20-10-2010
```

que me mandara un mensaje diciendo que la `fecha_inicio` ya se encuentra en un rango.

Tengo ésta parte de código.

```
@SuppressWarnings("null")
public String validarFechasEncuestas( String fecha_pub1, String fecha_pub_fin1, boolean activo)
{
    activo =false;
    String validarEncuesta = "";
    String queryvalidarEncuesta = "";
    queryvalidarEncuesta = "select * from encuestas where activo = "
                + activo + "true order by fecha_creacion" ;


    Calendar fechaInicio = Calendar.getInstance();
    fechaInicio.set(2017, 03, 05);

    Calendar fechaFinal = Calendar.getInstance();
    fechaFinal.set(2017, 03, 10);
    fechaFinal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

    Date fecha_pub = null;
    Date fecha_pub_fin = null;

    try
    {
        ResultSet rs = con.ejecutaQuery(queryvalidarEncuesta);
        while(rs.next())
        {
             while (fechaInicio.getTime().before(fechaFinal.getTime())) {
                 System.out.println(fechaInicio.getTime());
                 fechaInicio.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

                     if(fecha_pub.after(fecha_pub_fin) && fecha_pub_fin.before(fecha_pub) ){
                         activo = false;
                     }
                }

        }
        validarEncuesta = rs.getString("count");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Hola tuviste un error");
    }
    return validarEncuesta;
}
```

Comment: ¿La validación es en lado de base de datos o en java o en javascript?

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar el código con lo que intentaste hasta ahora? De esa forma, ayuda a generar contexto y permite que sea más sencillo poder responder sobre la base de tu código

Comment: En java amigo user2930137

Comment: ¿y en qué tipo de datos está almacenada la tabla de rangos de fecha entonces?

Answer (score -1):

No especificas la base de datos que usas, pero si usas algún sql, puede realizar una consulta como

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tu_tabla 
WHERE rango_inicio_que_deseas BETWEEN fecha_inicio AND fecha_fin
OR rengo_fin_que_deseas BETWEEN fecha_inicio AND fecha_fin
```

Si a columna regresa algo mayor a 0, ya existe en algún rango y puedes decir que no se realice el insert

Comment: Según entiendo, la pregunta busca comparar 2 rangos (no una fecha contra un rango)

Comment: Si quisiera ingresar por ejemplo el rango de la columna de 17 a 20, si el rango de inicio con realizar la consulta en le regresará si existe en algún rango, y al existir, quiere decir que el rango ya existe,

Comment: y si fuese del 1 al 21?

Comment: Me faltaba eso, que se compare también la condición del final del rango en el where

Comment: De todas formas el autor recién aclaró que la pregunta no es en SQL sino en Java (por eso en estos casos conviene esperar a que el autor aclare antes de responder)

Answer (score -1):

Necesitas hacer una primera consulta que te diga si existe ese registro:

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) /* Cualquier campo de tu tabla */
  FROM Tu_Tabla
 WHERE 'Fecha_proporcionada_inicio' BETWEEN fecha_inicio AND fecha_fin
       OR 'Fecha_proporcionada_fin' BETWEEN fecha_inicio AND fecha_fin
```

Esta consulta te devolverá un número que deberás evaluar; si es mayor a 0, entonces ya existe ese rango.

Comment: Según entiendo, la pregunta busca comparar 2 rangos (no una fecha contra un rango)

Comment: Tiene que comparar no el rango, sino solo dos fechas y comprobar si existe alguna de ellas dentro de uno de los rangos existentes.

Comment: y si el rango a comparar en el ejemplo de la pregunta fuese del día 1 al 21?

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM Tu_Tabla WHERE '2010-10-01' BETWEEN fecha_inicio AND fecha_fin OR '2010-10-21' BETWEEN fecha_inicio AND fecha_fin`
-------
Ya veo lo que dices. Bueno, eso no está definido en la pregunta... de hecho es muy ambigua. Me limitaré a responder lo expresado en la pregunta.

Comment: eso no sería verdadero para ninguno de los casos del ejemplo de la pregunta. Sin embargo, el autor recién aclaró que la pregunta no es en SQL sino en Java (por eso en estos casos conviene esperar a que el autor aclare antes de responder)

Comment: De hecho esa "aclaración" no me quedó clara porque sólo interpreto que su aplicación está en Java, y hacer filtros de datos en el ejecutable es mala idea. No sé si es un ejercicio de escuela (que no creo) o solo es bastante inexperto desde hace cuatro meses.